# SQL - How to combine 3 dates from 3 different tables (BigQuery)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Need to have one view for each agent, and want to aggregate all dates to include all metrics

**Basic Information:-**

- In the **productivity** table carries the information like as follows:

  ```
    | Handled_DATE   | Agent_Email           | Handled  | Missed
    |:-----------:  |:-------------:         |:--------:|:------:|
    |2013-11-05     |  Agent_01@google.com   |    80    |    9
    |2013-11-06     |   Agent_02@google.com  |    60    |   15
    |2013-11-07     |   Agent_03@google.com  |    70    |    7
    |2013-11-08     |   Agent_04@google.com  |    55    |   13
    |2013-11-09     |   Agent_01@google.com  |    73    |    5
    |2013-11-10     |   Agent_01@google.com  |    64    |   14
  ```
- In the **Quality** table carries the information like this:

  ```
    | Monitored_DATE  | Agent_Email          | Bussiness_Critical | Failed
    |:-----------:  |:-------------:         |:-------------:     |:-----------:|
    |2013-11-05     |  Agent_01@google.com   |    2               |    2
    |2013-11-06     |   Agent_01@google.com  |    1               |    1
    |2013-11-07     |   Agent_01@google.com  |    4               |    4
    |2013-11-08     |   Agent_04@google.com  |    1               |    1
  ```

In the **Absentieesm** table it carries the information like this:

```
| Attendance_Date | Agent_Email           | Attendance | Late_min
|:-----------:    |:-------------:        |:----------:|:-----------:|
|2013-11-05       |  Agent_01@google.com  |    Attend  |    9
|2013-11-06       |  Agent_01@google.com  |    Sick    |    0
|2013-11-07       |  Agent_01@google.com  |    Sick    |    0
|2013-11-08       |  Agent_04@google.com  |    55      |   13
|2013-11-10       |  Agent_01@google.com  |    Attend  |    0
```

**Desired Output**

```
| DATE       | Agent_Email           | Handled | Missed | Business_Critical | Failed |Attendance|Late_min
|:---------- |:-------------:        |:-------:|:------:|:-----------------:|:-----: |:--------:|:------:|
|2013-11-05  |  Agent_01@google.com  |    80   |    9   |       2           |   2    |  Attend  |   9
|2013-11-06  |  Agent_01@google.com  |    0    |    0   |       1           |   1    |  sick    |   0
|2013-11-07  |  Agent_01@google.com  |    0    |    0   |       4           |   4    |  sick    |   0
|2013-11-08  |  Agent_01@google.com  |    0    |    0   |       0           |   0    |  sick    |   0
|2013-11-09  |  Agent_01@google.com  |    73   |    5   |       0           |   0    |  NA      |   0
|2013-11-10  |  Agent_01@google.com  |    64   |   14   |       0           |   0    |  Attend  |   0
```

Comment: What did you do so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Desired Output]

Try this code - let me know if it helps.

````
WITH Date AS
( 
    SELECT DISTINCT date1 
    FROM
        (SELECT p.handled_date AS date1 
         FROM `productivity` AS p 
         UNION ALL
         SELECT q.Monitored_DATE AS date1 
         FROM `Quality` AS q 
         UNION ALL
         SELECT a.Attendance_Date AS date1 
         FROM `Absentieesm` AS a
        )
),
Agent AS 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT Agent_Email 
    FROM
        (SELECT p.Agent_Email AS Agent_Email 
         FROM `productivity` AS p 
         UNION ALL
         SELECT q.Agent_Email AS Agent_Email 
         FROM `Quality` AS q 
         UNION ALL
         SELECT a.Agent_Email AS Agent_Email 
         FROM `Absentieesm` AS a
        )
)
SELECT DISTINCT
    Date1,
    Agent.Agent_Email,
    IFNULL(Handled, 0) AS Handled, 
    IFNULL(Missed, 0) AS Missed, 
    IFNULL(Business_Critical, 0) AS Business_Critical, 
    IFNULL(Failed, 0) AS Failed, 
    IFNULL(Attendance, NULL) Attendance, 
    IFNULL(Late_min, 0) AS Late_min
FROM
    Agent, Date
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    `productivity` p ON p.Agent_Email = Agent.Agent_Email 
                     AND p.Handled_DATE = Date.Date1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    `Quality` q ON q.Agent_Email = Agent.Agent_Email 
                AND q.Monitored_DATE = Date.Date1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    `Absentieesm` a ON a.Agent_Email = Agent.Agent_Email 
                    AND a.Attendance_Date = Date.Date1
ORDER BY
    Agent_Email, Date1
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Join the tables with `Agent_Email` and respective `dates` as follows:

```
SELECT p.handled_date as date,
       p.Agent_Email, p.Handled, p.Missed 
       q.Business_Critical, q.Failed 
       a.Attendance, a.Late_min
FROM Productivity as p
LEFT JOIN Quality as q
  ON p.Agent_Email = q.Agent_Email
  AND p.handled_date = q.Monitored_DATE
LEFT JOIN absentieesm as a
  ON p.Agent_Email = a.Agent_Email
  AND p.handled_date = a.Attendance_DATE
```

Note - Keep the table which has most of the Agents as `LEFT TABLE`